# Is it possible to add a custom keyword?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using Json.NET schema, I am trying to create the simple schema:

```
{
   "type": "object",
   "customKeyWord": "customValue",
   "properties": [

   ]
}
```

Is it possible to create a custom keyword at the top level like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Specs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html):

> **6.4. Extending JSON Schema**
>
> Implementations MAY define additional keywords to JSON Schema. Save for explicit agreement, schema authors SHALL NOT expect these additional keywords to be supported by peer implementations. Implementations SHOULD ignore keywords they do not support.

Comment: I meant more of, does the JSON.net Schema library support it?

Comment: I don't think so, but Manatee.Json does.  (Disclaimer: I'm the author) Docs: https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/usage/schema.html#extending-schemas